# Android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts_details (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts_details(..) VALUES (?,??,?)

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I am using the listed code as a database help file but whenever I run the code I get the listed error message. Can someone please tell me if my code is correct or not? Pleas note that I am new to database and posted my question here to learn something. Thanks
Databasehelper.java

```
   public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DB_NAME = "saif_groupgrabber.db";
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.education.saifgroupgrabber/databases/";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TAG = "DataDbAdapter";
private String dbScriptFile = "db/main.sql";
private final Context mCtx;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory) null, 4);
    this.mCtx = context;
}

public static int copyAllBytes(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Copying all Bytes");
    byte[] bArr = new byte[4096];
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        int read = inputStream.read(bArr);
        if (read == -1) {
            return i;
        }
        outputStream.write(bArr, 0, read);
        i += read;
    }
}

public static int executeSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase, String[] strArr) {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Executing statements");
    int i = 0;
    for (String trim : strArr) {
        String trim2 = trim.trim();
        if (trim2.length() > 0) {
            sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(trim2);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

public static byte[] readAllBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Reading all Bytes");
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    copyAllBytes(inputStream, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}

public void backup(String str) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(this.mCtx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString()));
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(str);
        byte[] bArr = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            int read = fileInputStream.read(bArr);
            if (read > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(bArr, 0, read);
            } else {
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                fileInputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(this.mCtx, "Backup Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this.mCtx, "Unable to backup database. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void backupEveryTime(String str) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(this.mCtx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString()));
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(str);
        byte[] bArr = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            int read = fileInputStream.read(bArr);
            if (read > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(bArr, 0, read);
            } else {
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                fileInputStream.close();
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception unused) {
    }
}

public void deleteDataBase() {
    this.mCtx.deleteDatabase(this.mCtx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString());
}

public void executeSqlScript(String str) throws IOException {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Executing SQL script");
    int executeSqlStatements = executeSqlStatements(this.mDb, new String(readAsset(str), "UTF-8").split(";(\\s)*[\n\r]"));
    Log.i("DataDbAdapter", "Executed " + executeSqlStatements + " statements from SQL script '" + str + "'");
}

public String getDatabasePath() {
    return this.mCtx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
}

public void importDB(String str) {
    String file = this.mCtx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(str));
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] bArr = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            int read = fileInputStream.read(bArr);
            if (read > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(bArr, 0, read);
            } else {
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                fileInputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(this.mCtx, "Import Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this.mCtx, "Unable to import database. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase) {
    this.mDb = sQLiteDatabase;
    Log.v("DataDbAdapter", "About to create the database");
    try {
        executeSqlScript(this.dbScriptFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {


    }
}

public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase) {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Opened the database");
    super.onOpen(sQLiteDatabase);
    if (!sQLiteDatabase.isReadOnly()) {
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
    Log.w("DataDbAdapter", "Upgrading database from version " + i + " to " + i2 + ", which will destroy all old data");
    if (i < 3) {
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(DatabaseUpdateLog.Version3.DATABASE_CREATE_SUPER_GROUP_1);
    }
    if (i < 4) {
        sQLiteDatabase.execSQL(DatabaseUpdateLog.Version4.DATABASE_CREATE_CHATBOT_1);
    }
}

public byte[] readAsset(String str) throws IOException {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Reading asset " + str);
    InputStream open = this.mCtx.getAssets().open(str);
    try {
        return readAllBytes(open);
    } finally {
        open.close();
    }
}
```

}

ContactDetailsDataBaseAdapter.java

```
    public class ContactsDetailsDbAdapter {
public static final String CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME = "contact_add_datetime";
public static final String CONTACT_GROUP_ID = "contact_group_id";
public static final String CONTACT_GROUP_NAME = "contact_group_name";
public static final String CONTACT_ID = "contact_id";
public static final String CONTACT_NAME = "contact_name";
public static final String CONTACT_NUMBER = "contact_number";
public static final String CONTACT_STATUS = "contact_status";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contacts_details";
public static final String TAG = "DataDbAdapter";
public DatabaseHelper DatabaseHelper;
private final Context mCtx;
public SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private ContactsDetailsDbAdapter d;

public ContactsDetailsDbAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mCtx = context;
}

public void close() {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Closing the database");
    this.DatabaseHelper.close();
}

public boolean deleteData(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = this.mDb;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("contact_id=");
    sb.append(str);
    return sQLiteDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, sb.toString(), (String[]) null) > 0;
}

public boolean deleteDataNumber(String str) {
    return this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, d.r("contact_number='", str, "'"), (String[]) null) > 0;
}

private String r(String s, String str, String s1) {
    return s;
}

public boolean deleteGroupData(String str) {
    return this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, d.r("contact_group_id='", str, "'"), (String[]) null) > 0;
}

public Cursor fetchAllActiveDetails(String str) {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_group_id=? AND contact_status=?", new String[]{str, "ACTIVE"}, (String) null, (String) null, "contact_id ASC");
}

public Cursor fetchAllActiveDetailsUnique(String str) {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_group_id=? AND contact_status=?", new String[]{str, "ACTIVE"}, CONTACT_NUMBER, (String) null, "contact_id ASC");
}

public Cursor fetchAllDetails() {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, (String) null, (String[]) null, (String) null, (String) null, (String) null);
}

public Cursor fetchAllDetails(String str) {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_group_id=?", new String[]{str}, (String) null, (String) null, "contact_id ASC");
}

public Cursor fetchAllDetails(String str, String str2) {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_group_id=? AND contact_status=?", new String[]{str, "ACTIVE"}, CONTACT_NUMBER, (String) null, "contact_id ASC", str2);
}

public Cursor fetchAllInactiveContact(String str) {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_status=?  AND contact_number=?", new String[]{"INACTIVE", str}, (String) null, (String) null, (String) null);
}

public Cursor fetchAllInactiveContactName(String str) {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_status=?  AND contact_name=?", new String[]{"INACTIVE", str}, (String) null, (String) null, (String) null);
}

public Cursor fetchAllInactiveDetails() {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_status=?", new String[]{"INACTIVE"}, (String) null, (String) null, (String) null);
}

public Cursor fetchContactDetails(String str) {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_GROUP_ID, CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, CONTACT_STATUS, CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME}, "contact_id=?", new String[]{str}, (String) null, (String) null, (String) null);
}

public boolean inactiveContats(String str, String str2, ContentValues contentValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = this.mDb;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("contact_name LIKE '%");
    sb.append(str);
    sb.append("%' OR  ");
    sb.append(CONTACT_NUMBER);
    sb.append(" LIKE '%");
    return sQLiteDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, contentValues, d.s(sb, str2, "%'"), (String[]) null) > 0;
}

private String s(StringBuilder sb, String str2, String s) {
    return str2;
}

public long insertData(ContentValues contentValues) {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Inserting into com.example.saifgroupgraber.db");
    return this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, (String) null, contentValues);
}

public ContactsDetailsDbAdapter open() {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Opening the database");
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
    this.DatabaseHelper = databaseHelper;
    this.mDb = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public boolean updateDetails(String str, ContentValues contentValues) {
    return this.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, contentValues, d.q("contact_id=", str), (String[]) null) > 0;
}

private String q(String s, String str) {
    return s;
}
```

}

Error that shows is.....

1. no such table: contacts_details
   2024-03-08 14:46:17.935 15534-15593 SQLiteDatabase          pid-15534                            E  Error inserting contact_add_datetime=2024-03-08 14:46:17 contact_group_id= contact_group_name= contact_name=83 contact_number=+923004767178
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts_details (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts_details(contact_add_datetime,contact_group_id,contact_group_name,contact_name,contact_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)

Comment: "no such table: contacts_details" this part explains it all, I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error is due to table is not created and you are doing inserting into the table.

how it is possible when the table is not created and we enter some entry in it?

first, you have to create a table for data entries.

please make the following changes in DatabaseHelper class

replace with these functions in DatabaseHelper class and change it accordingly with your code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query;

    query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName
            + "( " + id + " INT PRIMARY KEY, "
            + name + " TEXT, "
            + nextField1 + " TEXT, "
            + nextField2 + " INT)";

    Log.e("create Query1", query);
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);
    onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

and 1 more thing sometimes after changing the database code, it crashes the app. so when this problem occure, you have to increase the database version i.e

```
 public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory) null, 4);
    this.mCtx = context;
}
```

here 4 is the database version, and then you have to increase it (this time to 5) whenever a crash occurs.

In your code, you are execute it through script i.e private String dbScriptFile = "db/main.sql";
so please check db/main.sql file is present in project.

if main.sql is not present, then do the manual code for table creation which I have provide above.

Comment: Best person, thank you. I am now working as per your instructions and informing you.

Comment: Thanks for help. i have solved this matter.

Comment: I need your help regarding another question. I will be grateful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78139169/how-to-load-android-database-sqlite-table-data-into-spinner-table-has-data-but

Comment: I have answer the question, please see