# How to load Android.database.sqlite table data into spinner? (Table has data but not loading)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, listview

I am using the following code to load sqlite database table information into a spinner. I am saving the data in the table through saving data activity and trying to getting the saved data in a spinner of getting data activity. When i open getting data activity from getting data of database table into spinner, nothing showing in spinner. I don't understand why data is not getting in spinner. I have some doubts about this method of my code.---  public void GetGroup() ---  Can someone please help regarding this?

```
 public class ContactsList extends BaseActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private static final String TAG = ContactsList.class.getSimpleName();
public ListView j;
public Spinner k;
public ContactsListViewAdapter l;
public ArrayList<ContactsListModel> m = new ArrayList<>();
/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public ProgressDialog mProgress;
public ArrayList<ContactsListModel> n = new ArrayList<>();
public LinearLayout o;
public List<String> p = new ArrayList();
public List<String> q = new ArrayList();
public List<String> r = new ArrayList();
public String s = "";
public String t = "";
public String u = "";
public boolean v = false;
public boolean w = false;
public String x;
private Cursor fetchAllBatchDetails;
private String group_id;

public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    public LoadData() {
        ContactsList.this.mProgress.show();
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public Boolean doInBackground(Void... voidArr) {
        ContactsList.this.n.clear();
        ContactsDetailsDbAdapter contactsDetailsDbAdapter = new ContactsDetailsDbAdapter(ContactsList.this);
        contactsDetailsDbAdapter.open();
        Cursor fetchAllDetails = ContactsList.this.t.equals("") ? contactsDetailsDbAdapter.fetchAllDetails() : contactsDetailsDbAdapter.fetchAllDetails(ContactsList.this.t);
        while (fetchAllDetails.moveToNext()) {
            ContactsList.this.n.add(new ContactsListModel(fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_ID)), fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NAME)), fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NUMBER)), fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NUMBER)), fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NUMBER)), fetchAllDetails.getString(fetchAllDetails.getColumnIndex(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NUMBER))));
        }
        contactsDetailsDbAdapter.close();
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean bool) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        ContactsList.this.m.clear();
        ContactsList contactsList = ContactsList.this;
        contactsList.m.addAll(contactsList.n);
        ContactsList.this.l.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ContactsList.this.j.invalidateViews();
        ContactsList.this.mProgress.dismiss();
        int i = 0;
        if (ContactsList.this.l.getCount() > 0) {
            Context applicationContext = ContactsList.this.getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, ContactsList.this.l.getCount() + " contacts displayed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            linearLayout = ContactsList.this.o;
            i = 8;
        } else {
            linearLayout = ContactsList.this.o;
        }
        linearLayout.setVisibility(i);
    }
}

public class SaveVCFContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    public SaveVCFContacts() {
        ContactsList.this.mProgress.show();
    }

    public Integer doInBackground(Void... voidArr) {
        int i;
        Exception e;
        int i2 = 0;
        try {
            ArrayList<ContactsListModel> arrayList = ContactsList.this.l.groupData;
            i = 0;
            while (i2 < arrayList.size()) {
                try {
                    ContactsListModel contactsListModel = arrayList.get(i2);
                    if (!MyFunctions.contactExists(ContactsList.this, contactsListModel.getContactNumber())) {
                        i++;
                        String contactName = contactsListModel.getContactName();
                        if (contactName.equals("Unknown")) {
                            contactName = ContactsList.this.u + AnalyticsConstants.DELIMITER_MAIN + i;
                        }
                        ContactsList.this.addContact(contactName, contactsListModel.getContactNumber());
                    }
                    i2++;
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e = e2;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Integer.valueOf(i);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e3) {
            e = e3;
            i = 0;
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Integer.valueOf(i);
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(i);
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Integer num) {
        ContactsList.this.mProgress.dismiss();
        Context applicationContext = ContactsList.this.getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, num + " contacts are saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public class ShareContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {
    public ShareContacts() {
        ContactsList.this.mProgress.show();
    }

    public File doInBackground(Void... voidArr) {
        File file;
        IOException e;
        file = new File(ContactsList.this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), ContactsList.this.x);
        try {
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(file);
            ArrayList<ContactsListModel> arrayList = ContactsList.this.l.groupData;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                ContactsListModel contactsListModel = arrayList.get(i);
                printStream.println(contactsListModel.getContactName() + "," + contactsListModel.getContactNumber());
            }
            printStream.flush();
            printStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e = e2;
            e.printStackTrace();
            return file;
        }
        return file;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(File file) {
        ContactsList.this.mProgress.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
        Uri uriForFile = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 ? FileProvider.getUriForFile(ContactsList.this, "com.invotech.whatspromo.provider", file) : Uri.fromFile(file);
        if (file.exists()) {
            intent.setType("text/*");
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", uriForFile);
            ContactsList.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share File"));
        }
    }
}

public class ShareVCFContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {
    public ShareVCFContacts() {
        ContactsList.this.mProgress.show();
    }

    public File doInBackground(Void... voidArr) {
        File file = null;
        File file2 = new File(ContactsList.this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "whatspromo.vcf");
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file2);
            ArrayList<ContactsListModel> arrayList = ContactsList.this.l.groupData;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                ContactsListModel contactsListModel = arrayList.get(i);
                fileWriter.write("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
                fileWriter.write("VERSION:2.1\r\n");
                fileWriter.write("N:" + contactsListModel.getContactID() + ";" + contactsListModel.getContactName() + ";;;\r\n");
                fileWriter.write("FN:" + contactsListModel.getContactName() + " " + contactsListModel.getContactID() + "\r\n");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("TEL;CELL:");
                sb.append(contactsListModel.getContactNumber());
                sb.append("\r\n");
                fileWriter.write(sb.toString());
                fileWriter.write("END:VCARD\r\n");
            }
            fileWriter.close();
            return file2;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e = e;
            file = file2;
            e.printStackTrace();
            return file;
        }
    }

    public void onPostExecute(File file) {
        ContactsList.this.mProgress.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
        Uri uriForFile = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 ? FileProvider.getUriForFile(ContactsList.this, "com.invotech.whatspromo.provider", file) : Uri.fromFile(file);
        if (file.exists()) {
            intent.setType("text/*");
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", uriForFile);
            ContactsList.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share File"));
        }
    }
}


public void Shake(View view) {
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(-5.0f, 5.0f, 1, 0.5f, 1, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(250);
    rotateAnimation.setStartOffset(50);
    rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(2);
    rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(5.0f));
    view.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}


public void addContact(String str, String str2) {
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValue("account_type", (Object) null).withValue("account_name", (Object) null).build());
    if (str != null) {
        arrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI).withValueBackReference("raw_contact_id", 0).withValue("mimetype", "vnd.android.cursor.item/name").withValue("data1", str).build());
    }
    if (str2 != null) {
        arrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI).withValueBackReference("raw_contact_id", 0).withValue("mimetype", "vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2").withValue("data1", str2).withValue("data2", 2).build());
    }
    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch("com.android.contacts", arrayList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Context applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
        StringBuilder u2 = ContactsList.this.u("Exception: ");
        u2.append(e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, u2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private StringBuilder u(String s) {
    return null;
}


public void showContacts() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 || checkSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        new SaveVCFContacts().execute(new Void[0]);
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"}, PointerIconCompat.TYPE_COPY);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public void AddContactDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(1);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_contact);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 17367048, this.q);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.drpdown_item);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.groupSpinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long j) {
            ContactsList contactsList = ContactsList.this;
            contactsList.s = "";
            contactsList.u = "";
            contactsList.s = contactsList.p.get(i);
            ContactsList contactsList2 = ContactsList.this;
            contactsList2.u = contactsList2.q.get(i);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
    spinner.setSelection(this.p.indexOf(this.t));
    if (this.w) {
        spinner.setEnabled(false);
    }
    final CountryCodePicker countryCodePicker = (CountryCodePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ccp);
    final TextInputEditText textInputEditText = (TextInputEditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.contactname_edit_text);
    final TextInputEditText textInputEditText2 = (TextInputEditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.contactnumber_edit_text);
    countryCodePicker.registerCarrierNumberEditText(textInputEditText2);
    textInputEditText.requestFocus();
    ((Switch) dialog.findViewById(R.id.subscribeSW)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeImageView)).setOnClickListener(view -> dialog.dismiss());
    final Dialog dialog2 = dialog;
    ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ContactsList.this.s.equals("")) {
                ContactsList.this.Shake(spinner);
                Toast.makeText(ContactsList.this.getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Group", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (ContactsList.this.L(textInputEditText, "")) {
                textInputEditText.setError("Enter Name");
            } else if (ContactsList.this.L(textInputEditText2, "")) {
                textInputEditText2.setError("Enter Number");
            } else {
                ContactsDetailsDbAdapter contactsDetailsDbAdapter = new ContactsDetailsDbAdapter(ContactsList.this);
                contactsDetailsDbAdapter.open();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NAME, textInputEditText.getText().toString());
                contentValues.put(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_NUMBER, countryCodePicker.getFullNumberWithPlus());
                contentValues.put(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_GROUP_ID, ContactsList.this.s);
                contentValues.put(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_GROUP_NAME, ContactsList.this.u);
                contentValues.put(ContactsDetailsDbAdapter.CONTACT_ADD_DATETIME, MyFunctions.getDateTime());
                contactsDetailsDbAdapter.insertData(contentValues);
                contactsDetailsDbAdapter.close();
                dialog2.dismiss();
                new LoadData().execute(new Void[0]);
            }
        }
    });
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(-1, -2);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(17170445);
    dialog.show();
}

private boolean L(TextInputEditText textInputEditText, String s) {
    return false;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public void EditGroupDialog(final String str, String str2) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(1);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_group);
    final TextInputEditText textInputEditText = (TextInputEditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.groupname_edit_text);
    textInputEditText.setText(str2);
    textInputEditText.requestFocus();
    ((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeImageView)).setOnClickListener(view -> dialog.dismiss());
    ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ContactsList.this.L(textInputEditText, "")) {
                textInputEditText.setError("Enter Group Name");
                return;
            }
            GroupDetailsDbAdapter groupDetailsDbAdapter = new GroupDetailsDbAdapter(ContactsList.this);
            groupDetailsDbAdapter.open();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(GroupDetailsDbAdapter.GROUP_NAME, textInputEditText.getText().toString());
            groupDetailsDbAdapter.updateBATCHDetails(str, contentValues);
            groupDetailsDbAdapter.close();
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ContactsList.this.getApplicationContext(), "Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ContactsList.this.finish();
        }
    });
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactsList.this.getApplicationContext(), "Long Press to Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            GroupDetailsDbAdapter groupDetailsDbAdapter = new GroupDetailsDbAdapter(ContactsList.this);
            groupDetailsDbAdapter.open();
            groupDetailsDbAdapter.deleteData(str);
            groupDetailsDbAdapter.close();
            ContactsDetailsDbAdapter contactsDetailsDbAdapter = new ContactsDetailsDbAdapter(ContactsList.this);
            contactsDetailsDbAdapter.open();
            contactsDetailsDbAdapter.deleteGroupData(str);
            contactsDetailsDbAdapter.close();
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ContactsList.this.getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ContactsList.this.finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
    ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton2)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsList.this, DeleteContactsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("GROUP_ID", str);
            ContactsList.this.startActivity(intent);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(-1, -2);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(17170445);
    dialog.show();
}


**@SuppressLint({"Range"})
public void GetGroup() {
    this.p.clear();
    this.q.clear();
    this.r.clear();
    GroupDetailsDbAdapter groupDetailsDbAdapter = new GroupDetailsDbAdapter(this);
    groupDetailsDbAdapter.open();
    Cursor fetchAllBatchDetails = groupDetailsDbAdapter.fetchAllBatchDetails();
    while (fetchAllBatchDetails.moveToNext()) {
        ContactsList.this.G(fetchAllBatchDetails, "group_id", this.p);
        ContactsList.this.G(fetchAllBatchDetails, GroupDetailsDbAdapter.GROUP_NAME, this.q);
        ContactsList.this.G(fetchAllBatchDetails, GroupDetailsDbAdapter.GROUP_NAME, this.r);
    }
    groupDetailsDbAdapter.close();
    if (this.p.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Group found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        groupNotFoundAlert();
    }
}
private void G(Cursor fetchAllBatchDetails, String group_id, List<String> p) {
    this.fetchAllBatchDetails = fetchAllBatchDetails;
    this.group_id = group_id;
    this.p = p;
}**


public void groupNotFoundAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle((CharSequence) "Group Not Found");
    builder.setMessage((CharSequence) "Please create a group first");
    builder.setPositiveButton((CharSequence) "OK", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            ContactsList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ContactsList.this, GroupList.class));
            ContactsList.this.finish();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}

public void onActivityResult(int i, int i2, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(i, i2, intent);
    if (i == 10 && i2 == -1) {
        new LoadData().execute(new Void[0]);
    }
}

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_contacts_list);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        this.t = extras.getString("GROUP_ID");
        this.u = extras.getString("GROUP_NAME");
        this.w = true;
    }
    //setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    setTitle("Contacts List");
    getSharedPreferences(PreferencesConstants.APP_MAIN_PREF, 0);
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    this.mProgress = progressDialog;
    progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    this.mProgress.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
    try {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
        Log.e("SearchActivity Toolbar", "You have got a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION");
    }
    this.k = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.groupSpinner);
    this.o = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.placeHolderLayout);
    this.j = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.groupListview);
    ContactsListViewAdapter contactsListViewAdapter = new ContactsListViewAdapter(this, this.m);
    this.l = contactsListViewAdapter;
    this.j.setAdapter(contactsListViewAdapter);
    this.j.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ContactsList.this.MoreOptionDialog();
        }
    });
    GetGroup();
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType") ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 17367048, this.r);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.drpdown_item);
    this.k.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    this.k.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long j) {
            ContactsList contactsList = ContactsList.this;
            contactsList.t = "";
            contactsList.u = contactsList.q.get(i);
            ContactsList contactsList2 = ContactsList.this;
            contactsList2.t = contactsList2.p.get(i);
            if (ContactsList.this.v) {
                new LoadData().execute(new Void[0]);
            }
            ContactsList.this.v = true;
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
    if (this.w) {
        this.k.setSelection(this.p.indexOf(this.t));
        this.k.setEnabled(false);
    }
}


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long j2) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactNameTextView);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("CONTACT_ID", ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactIdTextView)).getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new LoadData().execute(new Void[0]);
}
  }
   
  **This is GroupDetailsDbAdapter.java**

     package com.education.saifgroupgrabber;
  public class GroupDetailsDbAdapter {
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "group_details";
public static final String GROUP_ADD_DATETIME = "group_add_datetime";
public static final String GROUP_ID = "group_id";
public static final String GROUP_NAME = "group_name";
public static final String TAG = "DataDbAdapter";
public DatabaseHelper DatabaseHelper;
private final Context mCtx;
public SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private GroupDetailsDbAdapter d;
private String s;
private String str;

public GroupDetailsDbAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mCtx = context;
}


public void close() {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Closing the database");
    this.DatabaseHelper.close();
}

public boolean deleteData(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase = this.mDb;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("group_id=");
    sb.append(str);
    return sQLiteDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, sb.toString(), (String[]) null) > 0;
}

public Cursor fetchAllBatchDetails() {
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{"group_id", 
GROUP_NAME, GROUP_ADD_DATETIME}, (String) null, (String[]) null, 
(String) null, (String) null, (String) null);
}

public long insertBatchData(ContentValues contentValues) {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Inserting into 
 com.example.shivanshu.rotaryhospital.db");
    return this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, (String) null, 
 contentValues);
}

public GroupDetailsDbAdapter open() {
    Log.d("DataDbAdapter", "Opening the database");
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
    this.DatabaseHelper = databaseHelper;
    this.mDb = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public Cursor showALlBatchesWithContact() {
    return this.mDb.rawQuery("SELECT  * ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  contacts_details WHERE contact_group_id=group_id) AS 'COUNT' FROM group_details", (String[]) null);
}

public boolean updateBATCHDetails(String str, ContentValues contentValues) {
    return this.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, contentValues, this.q("group_id=", str), (String[]) null) > 0;
}

public String q(String s, String str) {
    this.s = s;
    this.str = str;
    return s;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType") ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 17367048, this.r);
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.drpdown_item);
this.k.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

change it like this

first check in Logcat that this.r is getting values or not.

if this.r have values then use below code for spinner adapter.

```
Log.e("tag", "this.r = " + this.r);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.r);      
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: if this.r is not getting values, issue is there then.

Comment: In logcat following is show. this.r = []

Comment: GetGroupDetails(fetchAllBatchDetails, GroupDetailsDbAdapter.GROUP_NAME, r);

Comment: this.r is An array  list string which is assigned as a new ArrayList and that is receiving data from a database table.

Comment: I have edit my question and included GroupDetailsDbAdapter.java file. Please check it again.

Comment: Means this.r has getting no values. but i think that it has values also. Please check my whole code and GroupDetailsDbAdapter.java file for correction if you can.

Comment: This line in the code I believe is the problem here. GetGroupDetails(fetchAllBatchDetails, GroupDetailsDbAdapter.GROUP_NAME, this.r)

Comment: ook, the reason of problem is GetGroup() is not finish yet and you are calling Spinner code, so spinner got an empty this.r.

now you have pass this.r with all values.

you have to change your code little bit.

Do GetGroup() on AsyncTask class.
In doInBackground fxn paste all code of GetGroup() and
onPostExecute you have to set spinner code.

Comment: do the changes and then share the updates.

Comment: and before chamges, do copy your project code in another place too for safe side.

Comment: I have do that you say but ,,, android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.education.saifgroupgrabber.ContactsList has leaked window DecorView@43b7d9b[Loading] that was originally added here
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:485)

Comment: I know this is related to the error that we are trying to show a Dialog after we have exited an Activity. While you can see what we have dismiss with all the dialogs we have opened.

Comment: please share code where you made changes

Comment: I put "GetGroup() method" into public Boolean doInBackground(Void... voidArr) { in public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> { and put spinner code into public void onPostExecute(Boolean bool) {.

Comment: why not ? I can definitely share my complete project with you. Please either provide me your email address or your WhatsApp number. So that I can provide you my complete project and you can view it and correct the mistakes۔

Comment: Thank you . If you consider it appropriate, please also provide me your email address. It will be easy for me to provide you with the basic information about the project I am developing.

Comment: And sorry your provider number is not on whats app.

Comment: Please check your email address. Thanks

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: Thanks Sir Muhammad Shah. i have changed GetGroupDetails() method as you say.